# Whenever I am moving to different tab screens it shows the error "Accessing the state property of the route object is not supported"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am making a food delivery app whenever I am switching to different screens in tab bar it shows the error

```
Accessing the 'state' property of the 'route' object is not supported. If you want to get the focused route name, use the 'getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute' helper instead:
```

The error says me to go the following link [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/screen-options-resolution)

Here is the code of my MainTabScreen which contains the tab navigator

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const tabOptions = {
  activeTintColor: "red",
  inactiveTintColor: "black",

  showLabel: false,
};
const MainTabScreen = () => {

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabOptions={tabOptions}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="MainHome"
        component={MainHomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => (
             <Icon.Home color={color} height={28} width={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="MainCart"
        component={MainCartScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => (
            <Icon.ShoppingCart color={color} width={28} height={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="MainProfile"
        component={MainProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: () => (
             <Icon.User color={color} height={28} width={28} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default MainTabScreen;
```

My MainHomeScreen, MainCartScreen and MainProfileScreen looks similar to this

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const MainProfileScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default MainProfileScreen;
```

My package versions:

```
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.15",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.9",
    "@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input": "^1.3.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^1.4.2",
    "expo-font": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-location": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.12.3",
    "expo-secure-store": "~10.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "firebase": "^8.2.3",
    "lottie-react-native": "4.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-feather": "^1.1.2",
    "react-native-form-select-picker": "^0.0.12",
    "react-native-input-spinner": "^1.7.11",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webview": "11.6.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "recyclerlistview": "^3.0.5",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1"
```

Comment: please add more code, try to add the screen code which has the error

Comment: Could you provide us with the version of the packages you are using? E.g. `@react-navigation/native` `@react-navigation/stack` and so on?

Comment: Btw. your link redirects me to `about:blank#blocked`

Comment: I'm not really sure why this is happening, could you create a reproducible example on something like https://snack.expo.dev/.

Answer (score 1):

i am using the same logic and this way of implementation works fine for me,

I am using react-navigation-v5

Give it a shot, Cheers

I MainScreen index.tsx I have the tab navigator

```
      <Tab.Navigator
    sceneContainerStyle={{ backgroundColor: Theme.colors.white }}
    initialRouteName="Profile"
    screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => {

        if (route.name === 'Profile') {
          return <AntDesign name="profile" size={size} color={color} />
        }
        if (route.name === 'Settings') {
          return <FontAwesome5 name="settings" size={size} color={color} />
        }
      },
    })}
    tabBarOptions={{
      activeTintColor: Theme.colors.blue,
      inactiveTintColor: Theme.colors.greyShade2
    }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={SettingsScreen} />

  </Tab.Navigator>
```

and on your Main Profile screen in Stack.screen call it like this.
This is how I called my MainScreen(where i have Tab navigator) in Stack

```
          <Stack.Screen
        name="MainScreen"
        options={({ route, navigation }) => {
          const focusedRoute = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) || 'Profile'
          return {
            cardStyle: { backgroundColor: Theme.colors.white },
            title: focusedRoute,
            headerTitleAlign: 'left',
            headerStyle: {
              height: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? Constants.statusBarHeight + 68 : 68
            },
            headerTitle: () => {
              if (focusedRoute === 'Profile') {
                return (
                  <Div row alignItems='center'>
                    <YourLogo />
                    <Text>Your header title</Text>
                  </Div>
                )
              }
              return <Text ml="lg" fontFamily="Gilroy-ExtraBold" fontSize={18}>{focusedRoute}</Text>
            },
            headerRight: () => {
              if (focusedRoute === 'Profile') {
                return (
                  <Div mr="lg">
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ padding: 10 }} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('SettingsScreen')}>
                      <SettingsIcon />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </Div>
                )
              }
              return null
            }
          }
        }}
        component={MainScreen} />
```

hope this helps. explore and customize your nav to your hearts content.
Good luck, Cheers

Comment: How do I implement ```headerShown: false```?

Comment: I do something like this inside the Stack.Screen

                 `options={({ route }) => {
          const routeName = getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route)
          switch (routeName) {
            case 'LandingScreen':
              return ({ swipeEnabled: false, headerShown: false })
            case 'LoginScreen':
              return ({ swipeEnabled: false, headerShown: false })
            default:
              return ({ headerShown: false })
          }`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to remove the prop { route } and replace with the hook useRoute

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-route/

Comment: Can you provide some code mate?

Comment: @AyushKumar they are talking about this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-route

Comment: Yes they are advising me to use **useRoute** but my error says me to go to [reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/screen-options-resolution/)

Comment: Yes yes, but there is code on that website.

Answer (score 0):

The error was because of the package **why-did-you-render** after commenting it from the imports the error goes away. Thanks everyone for the help and support.